# Add additional json structure to all WebApi's responses?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

*We are integrating with mobile software company to do our application in a mobile device.*

Our controller has ( simplification) methods like :

```
api/users/1
–GetUserById(...)

api/users/changePassword
–ChangePassword(Person p)
```

Ok.

The `ChangePassword` can return several applicative error codes ( password has already used , password too short , password bla bla...)

So  if ,for example, password has already been used , then the `HttpCode`  should be `200` returned with additional info

We agreed on this convention for every response :(  **additional** to the response data)

```
{
 "Success":0,
 "ErrorCode": 6,
 "ErrorMessage":"already used"
}
```

But this structure , as I said - should be in every response.

So till now -  for example : `api/users/1`  returned :

```
{
 "userId":1,
 "name":"John"
}
```

But now - the response should be :

```
{

 "data":
   {
    "userId":1,
    "name":"John"
   }
,
 "result": //no errors
    {
     "Success":0,
     "ErrorCode": 0,
     "ErrorMessage":""
    }

}
```

They always looking for the "result" object to see  the applicative response.

**Question**

I assume that the place which I should do it is in message handler after `base.SendAsync` ( response part)

But how should I wrap the regular response which I send via `Request.CreateResponseMessage` with the  format + values of  :

[image]

NB  , of course at the `Request.CreateResponseMessage` phase I already  have result object with the appropriate result codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time message handlers run in Web API pipeline, the result your action method has produced would have been serialized. An action filter would be a better option, since you can deal with objects, and you can do something like this.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var content = context.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (content != null)
        {
            content.Value =
                new MyResponse()
                {
                    Result = new Result() { Success = 0, ErrorCode = 6 },
                    Data = content.Value
                };
        }
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public int Success { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}

public class MyResponse
{
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The above code will work only for JSON and not XML.

Comment: Wow Badri , I almost feel uncomfortable but you always answer with codes and explanations - as an exact answer to the question. . Thank you very much!.

Comment: XML serializers cannot handle `object`.

Comment: My filter is not being called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), and on the [OnActionExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted(v=vs.118).aspx) Method you will get HttpActionExecutedContext where you can check the response message.

you can decorate your controlleror action by this attribute and return and create you own ResponseMessage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you  for the reply.OnActionExecuted is indeed the solution.

Comment: Omar Hi , is it possible now to go to chat ?